# in postgresql inner join gives result for id in single line

Tags: sql, postgresql

This is my query:

```
  SELECT    (sc.contract_number) AS id,
            to_char(sc.contract_date, 'DD/MM/YYYY') AS "Contract Date",
            (sc.cust_name) AS "Customer Name",
            (
             SELECT pt.product_desc
             FROM   product_product pp,
                    product_template pt
             WHERE  pt.id = pp.product_tmpl_id AND
                    type = 'service' AND
                    pt.name LIKE sc.pms_lines
            ) AS "PMS",
            CASE WHEN sc.parent_ref IS NULL THEN ROUND(sc.basic_amount)
                 ELSE 0
            END AS "New Amount",
            CASE WHEN sc.parent_ref IS NULL THEN 0
                 ELSE ROUND(sc.basic_amount)
            END AS "Renew Amount",
            ROUND(sc.service_tax_amount + sc.edu_tax_amount +
                  sc.hs_edu_tax_amount) AS "Service Tax",
            ROUND(sc.grand_total_amount) AS "Total"
  FROM      sale_contract sc
  INNER JOIN inspection_costing_line icl ON (sc.id = icl.id)
  WHERE     sc.contract_date BETWEEN '2015-03-02'
                             AND     '2015-03-10'
  ORDER BY  sc.contract_number ASC;
```

I am getting this result:

```
    id              | Contract Date |           Customer Name           | PMS             | New Amount | Renew Amount | Service Tax | Total 
--------------------|---------------|-----------------------------------|-----------------|------------|--------------|-------------|-----------
P114CO15004025      | 03/03/2015    | Farhan Farooqui                   | GSS             |          0 |         2200 |         272 |   2472
P114CO15004026      | 03/03/2015    | R K Builders                      | TSPO            |       3000 |            0 |         371 |   3371
P114CO15004027      | 03/03/2015    | Jivesh Terrace                    | PSS , IMM , PPS |          0 |        60000 |        7416 |  67416
```

Expected result

```
    id              | Contract Date |           Customer Name           | PMS             | New Amount | Renew Amount | Service Tax | Total 
--------------------|---------------|-----------------------------------|-----------------|------------|--------------|-------------|-----------
P114CO15004025      | 03/03/2015    | Farhan Farooqui                   | GSS             |          0 |         2200 |         272 |   2472
P114CO15004026      | 03/03/2015    | R K Builders                      | TSPO            |       3000 |            0 |         371 |   3371
P114CO15004027      | 03/03/2015    | Jivesh Terrace                    | PSS             |          0 |        60000 |        7416 |  67416
P114CO15004027      | 03/03/2015    | Jivesh Terrace                    | IMM             |          0 |        60000 |        7416 |  67416
P114CO15004027      | 03/03/2015    | Jivesh Terrace                    | PPS             |          0 |        60000 |        7416 |  67416
```

Comment: can you show how you join sales and invoices tables?

Comment: This is my query..
select col.name
from sale_contract  sc inner join inspection_costing_line icl on( sc.id = icl.id) where sc.contract_date between '2015-03-02' AND '2015-03-10'  order by sc.contract_number ASC;

Comment: @abhijeetmote . . . Edit your question with the real query you are using.  The version in the comment is not what you are running -- for instance, it only would return one column.

Comment: All that time I took removing all of your `&nbsp;`'s and HTML from your question, only to be reverted back :'(

Comment: I am sorry for that, this is the final change in question...

Comment: @abhijeetmote, take a look at the [Markdown Help](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) section for posting questions.  You do not need to format your question as HTML.

Comment: Thanks tom for helping in this(how to format
)... most of the time i wasted my time in formatting the question or answer while posting.. thanks one agian...

Comment: how to use string_agge in my case, its giving error

Comment: friends i didnt get the solution, may i know what is the right way to achieve it..??

Comment: you must post also the creation table script and some insert instructions, so we could build a test case for running the query

Answer (score 0):

you a are using the output of a select (select pt....) as a column try moving the select in the from clause, something like this:

```
SELECT    (sc.contract_number) AS id,
            to_char(sc.contract_date, 'DD/MM/YYYY') AS "Contract Date",
            (sc.cust_name) AS "Customer Name",
            pt.product_desc AS "PMS",
            CASE WHEN sc.parent_ref IS NULL THEN ROUND(sc.basic_amount)
                 ELSE 0
            END AS "New Amount",
            CASE WHEN sc.parent_ref IS NULL THEN 0
                 ELSE ROUND(sc.basic_amount)
            END AS "Renew Amount",
            ROUND(sc.service_tax_amount + sc.edu_tax_amount +
                  sc.hs_edu_tax_amount) AS "Service Tax",
            ROUND(sc.grand_total_amount) AS "Total"
  FROM      product_product pp, product_template pt, sale_contract sc
  INNER JOIN inspection_costing_line icl ON (sc.id = icl.id)
  WHERE     sc.contract_date BETWEEN '2015-03-02'
                             AND     '2015-03-10' and
            pt.id = pp.product_tmpl_id AND
            type = 'service' AND
            pt.name LIKE sc.pms_lines
  ORDER BY  sc.contract_number ASC;
```

I cannot test it but can be used as starting point

Comment: with your solution, the records which has more than one PMS are skipped out, according to me sub query is working fine... The problem is with the join.